# Not able to write to SDCard while screen is off even though I have PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I'm totally new to Java and Android, so I think I'm probably missing something obvious.
I'm writing an app where I sample the orientation sensor and write the result to a file on the SDCard as well as display it in a log on the screen.
Everything works fine while the screen is on. Since I want to also operate while the screen goes dark, I added code to acquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK.
From what I can tell, when the screen goes dark the sensors are still being sampled (making me think the wake lock worked), but none of the results are written to the SDCard. I think this is what is happening, because when I reawaken the screen by pressing the menu key, the log on the screen has all the transitions displayed that took place while the screen was off. But, when I look at the file created on the SD card, the only transitions recorded in the file are the ones that occurred while the screen was on.
As for how I'm writing the file I have tried (I think I'm saying this right...) a FileWriter wrapped in BufferedWriter, and a FileWriter wrapped in a FileOutputStream.
At first, the orientation sensor wasn't working even though I had the wake lock until I learned a work around where I added a BroadcastReceiver for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and when I get it, I unregister the orientation listener, then re-register it.
Do I need to "unregister" the FileWriter and "re-register" it or something?
The weird part is that the output file contains all orientation changes before the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF is received, and all of them after Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON is received when I power the screen back up, but nothing in between.

I'm writing for Android 1.6 (I have a G1)
My project is set to use SDK 4

Comment: P.S. People will hate your app if you use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. Huge battery drainer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if external storage is available as [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)? It may be simply unwritable at that time. There's also [code in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for a external storage BroadcastReceiver. You could use that to wait until storage is available before writing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I was checking if external storage was available in onResume(), so after reading your suggestion, I added the check every time I try to write to the file.  I then print the result of that test to the log on the screen so I can read it when I bring the screen back up.  Strangely, the result when the screen is off is always mExternalStorageWriteable == true, but yet nothing is written to the file.  Any idea where I go from here?

Comment: Are you closing the file? It's possible the flushing behaviour of android changes when the screen turns off. --- Try opening, writing, and closing a new file in your ACTION_SCREEN_OFF BroadcastReceiver. Then you'll know if writing is okay in a simple case.