# Android - How can i write to file when the screen times out

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

We are writing an (industry specific) application that maintains it's own log file (I know we should use the android log, but for business purposes we need to maintain this log file in a very specific format.) This app is not for mass market, and users will be well aware of the battery drain the app will suffer.

First the app has a service that must maintain a connection to a server at all times. We have achieved this through the use of a partial wakelock, which works as expected once the screen time's out.

Our problem however, when the screen time's out, our logger module ceases to write to a file located on external storage, once the screen is started again the logger resumes after a short period.

We know the app isn't being killed by the system (due to the foreground service) as when it is restarted everything remains as it should. (A restart brings us back to a different screen)

Is there another way to force the system to keep the stream to the file open? Why does the partial-wake-lock we hold not do this already?

There must be a way we can write to file at all times.

Comment: Looks like other people have had the same problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742829/not-able-to-write-to-sdcard-while-screen-is-off-even-though-i-have-partial-wake-l

Comment: I read this post before i posted, and performing the tests proved the same thing the OP had responded with. Unfortunately that post was dead since Jan. So I reposted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a device/platform specific issue, as the problem has fixed itself over time!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is hard to say. Given your description a partial wake lock is the best choice, it should prevent the CPU from going to sleep so that you can run whatever code you like for as long as you hold the wakelock. From your description it simply sounds like the partial wake lock is not taking effect. Check the code to make sure you are doing something like releasing the wakelock when the device display goes to sleep.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The wake lock is definately taking effect, without it the service stops pinging our server, and the server reports that the device has gone offline after approx 5 minutes from screen timeout. With the wakelock however the device stays online. Could it have something to do with threads? I was under the impression that a wakelock works across all threads. I will try to grab a lock with different threads and report the differences.

Comment: The thread you use won't make a difference, the wake lock applies to the CPU at a hardware level, it keeps the whole thing awake, all threads and all processes, that's one big reason it can be abused.